# Which event is fired when open an Android app from Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

I have a piece of JS code do the job: click the link, if an (Android) app is installed, start that app, otherwise show a popup (with some instruction to download app from store).
If the app is installed and started up, press "Back" button on the phone to return back to Chrome, above popup must disappear.

```
var android_app_link = "myapp://some.thing";
$("a[id^=this_is_id]").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!document.webkitHidden || !document.hidden) {
            show_android_popup();
        }
    }, 2000);
    window.location.href = android_app_link;
});
```

But `document.webkitHidden` and `document.hidden` doesn't seem to work, so after returned from app, the popup still there.

Any problems with my code? Which event is fired on Chrome when the app shown up, `blur` or something?

*I'm using Chrome 46 on Android 5.0*